# Pre-loading images in a one-page application

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, caching

I have a one-page Ajax application written in NodeJS that is *very* careful about error handling. If the connection with the server goes 100% down, widgets will have a "reload me" overlay which, when clicked, will attempt to reload the widget/

The problem I am having is this scenario:

- The application loads fine
- I kill the server
- I click on something that creates a widget
- The "reload" icon on top of the widget is not displayed because... well, the client tries to fetch it from the server, but the image is obviously not fetchable since the server is down!

I *can* place the image on a different server, but I don't want to go down that path as it's a bit of an overkill.

I tried putting `<img src="/app/hotplate/hotDojoWidgets/reload.png"></img>` on top of the app's page, but the client won't consider it -- it will try and reload instead.

What can I do, so that widget will always show the image?

Comment: Are you returning a `Last-Modified` header with the image response so that the browser can cache it?

Comment: Yep... `Last-Modified:Sun, 05 Jan 2014 05:42:50 GMT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the request goes to the dead server, I can't see how you will get away with a timeout and a broken picture as a result.

The usual way of avoiding server cache validation is to set headers like so:
`Cache-Control:public; max-age=` now + 1 year
`Expires:` now + 1 year
and no `Etag:` or `Last-modified:` that would only risk triggering a validation
(*well they should be "protected" by the `max-age` and/or `Expires` directives, but some exotic browser might be tempted to validate them anyway*).

However, a browser is free do dump any object from the cache (if the cache is full and this particular object is deemed too bulky and/or unsufficiently used to be worth caching).

Fiddling with HTTP headers alone cannot 100% guarantee your browser will not request a given object.

The only way to systematically avoid a broken link is to control the browser's cache behaviour directly.

If you're doing HTML5, [cache manifests](http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/) might be the solution.